# MifareUltralight: sector select causes TagLostException

Tags: java, android, nfc, rfid, mifare

I am trying to use SECTOR_SELECT to read and write to/from specified sectors, but get a `TagLostException` when I send the second part of the command through `MifareUltralight.transceive()`. How can I select and manipulate sectors?

I am using an Android Nexus 6 (6.0.1) to send commands to and get data from an NXP NTAG (NT3H1201). I am able to use the GET_VERSION command (60h) with transceive (both through `NfcA` and `MifareUltralight`).

The method I am using to select a sector:

```
public void selectSector(byte sector, MifareUltralight mifareUltralight) throws IOException {
    if (mifareUltralight.isConnected()) {
        mifareUltralight.close();
    }

    // SECTOR_SELECT command (see nxp p. 46)
    byte[] sectorSelectCmdPacket1 = new byte[2];
    byte[] sectorSelectCmdPacket2 = new byte[4];

    sectorSelectCmdPacket1[0] = (byte) 0xc2; // Sector select command
    sectorSelectCmdPacket1[1] = (byte) 0xff;

    sectorSelectCmdPacket2[0] = sector; // Memory sector to be selected; 1 for I2C 2k version
    sectorSelectCmdPacket2[1] = (byte) 0x00;
    sectorSelectCmdPacket2[2] = (byte) 0x00;
    sectorSelectCmdPacket2[3] = (byte) 0x00;

    mifareUltralight.connect();

    try {
        // ACK = 0A
        byte[] sectorSelectResp1 = mifareUltralight.transceive(sectorSelectCmdPacket1);
        Log.w(TAG, bytesToHex(sectorSelectResp1));
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.w(TAG, "selectSector: there was an exception while sending first sector select command");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    try {
        mifareUltralight.transceive(sectorSelectCmdPacket2);
        Log.w(TAG, "Second sector select command sent");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.w(TAG, "selectSector: there was an exception while sending second sector select command");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    mifareUltralight.close();
}
```

When I call the selectSector method, the first transceive completes but the second does not, resulting in the error

> android.nfc.TagLostException: Tag was lost.

How can I select and manipulate sectors without getting the `TagLostException`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's normal that the second stage of the SECTOR_SELECT command results in a `TagLostException`. This happens on many Android devices and is caused by the way the second stage of the SECTOR_SELECT command is acknowledged (passive ACK). You can safely continue to communicate with the tag after you received the exception for that specific command. Only if you receive a `TagLostException` for a command where you expect an explicit ACK/response data there is something wrong with the communication.

Also note that you should *not* close the connection after selecting the sector as this will reset the tag on some Android devices. Consequently, the sector may no longer be selected when you later re-connect the tag.

A typical sector select method would look something like this:

```
public boolean selectSector(int sector) throws IOException {
    byte[] cmd_sel1 = { (byte)0xC2, (byte)0xFF };
    byte[] cmd_sel2 = { (byte)sector, (byte)0x00, (byte)0x00, (byte)0x00 };

    byte[] result1 = transceive(cmd_sel1);
    if (result1 == null) {
        throw new TagLostException();
    } else if ((result1.length == 1) && ((result1[0] & 0x00A) == 0x000)) {
        // NACK response according to DigitalProtocol
        return false;
    } else {
        try {
            byte[] result2 = transceive(cmd_sel2);
            if (result2 == null) {
                throw new TagLostException();
            } else if ((result2.length == 1) && ((result2[0] & 0x00A) == 0x000)) {
                // NACK response according to DigitalProtocol
                return false;
            } else {
                return true;
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // passive ACK
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @fipoceilz7 I'm not aware of any useful public resources (other than trial-and-error and digging into the Android NFC stack yourself). We do offer trainings though ;-)

Comment: How much is it and where can I find more info?

Comment: would be great to mention that, when exception is thrown the sector will resets too as well as when close() is called.